# If $X \times X$ is normal, then is $X \times X \times X$ normal?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, dimension-theory-analysis, separation-axioms, product-space

I am looking at some topological dimension theory for product spaces, and in trying to construct a certain type of counterexample it's become relevant to consider the question in the title above.  I am interested in finding a normal space $X$ whose products with itself is *eventually* non-normal, but not immediately.

It's not actually important for my application that it happens in three steps as opposed to more.  An alternative question would be: Is there a normal space $X$ with $X \times X = Y$ normal, but $Y \times Y$ is not normal?

The original problem is here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315657/if-textdimx-times-x-2-textdimx-does-textdimxn-n-textdim

Thanks for any help!

As mentioned in a comment below, if we assume that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and that $X \times X \times X$ is completely normal, then $X$ is metrizable.  Thus it stands to reason that a compact counterexample may be harder (if not impossible) to construct.  The author in the linked paper wonders aloud if the complete normality of $X \times X$ is sufficient for the metrizability of $X$, so it may also be advisable to avoid cases where $X \times X$ is completely normal.

Comment: This is not an answer, but somehow related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2872102

Comment: Interesting result, I will mention it in an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A construction can be found in (or weaned from)

- *Przymusinski, Teodor C.*, [**Normality and paracompactness in finite and countable Cartesian products**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm-105-2-87-104), Fundam. Math. 105, 87-104 (1980). [ZBL0438.54021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0438.54021).

wherein the following remarkable result is proved:

> **Theorem 1.** For every $k$ and $m$ such that $1 \leq k \leq m \leq \omega$ there exists a separable and first coutnable space $X = X(k,m)$ such that
>
> 1. $X^n$ is paracompact (Lindelöf, subparacompact) if and only if $n < k$,
> 2. $X^n$ is normal (collectionwise normal) if and only if $n < m$.

In particular, we can construct a (normal) space such that the failure of normality of its powers happens first at any prescribed finite power.

Comment: Wow, what a result!