# Is product of perfect spaces perfect?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Let $X,Y$ be perfect topological spaces (e.g. every closed set is $G_\delta$). Is $X\times Y$ perfect?

I know that this isn't true for uncountable products, for example $[0,1]$ is perfect because every metric space is perfect, but $[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$ is not perfect because every countable intersection of open sets containing the zero function has more than one element. Therefore the singleton of the zero function is closed but not $G_\delta$.

However, is it true for finite products? For countable products?

Answer (score 2):

No, even for the square of a compact $T_4$ such space, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2873087/4280) for a proof. [Double Arrow space](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/double-arrow-space/) is a concrete and classic counterexample.

Comment: Is there a product of two $T_6$ spaces that is $T_5$ but not $T_6$?

Comment: @Dani yes under $\Diamond$, a modification of a classic example gives $X$ perfectly normal with $X^2$ not perfectly normal but $T_5$. $X$ is also countably compact (but not compact). In ZFC I don’t know yet.

Comment: See [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82064183.pdf) for the paper @Dani