# A normal space that is not completely normal and has countable pseudo-character

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

I am looking for a $T_4$ space (normal + $T_1$) that is not $T_5$ (completely normal +$T_1$), but such that every singleton is the countable intersection of open sets. Or, alternatively, a proof that none exists.

Some background:

A $G_{\delta}$ normal space, i.e. a normal space where every closed set is the countable intersection of open sets, is perfectly normal and therefore is also completely normal.
What about a normal space where every singleton is the countable intersection of open sets? i.e. a normal space with a countable pseudo-character (if I understand correctly the term "pseudo-character"). Does such space have to be completely normal?

Comment: It's been a long while since I did topology, but have you looked in the book "Counterexamples in Topology"?  It's got a ton of weird edge cases

Comment: Take [Alexandroff's double arrow space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_interval) $A$ and consider its square $X=A\times A$. Since $A$ is compact $T_2$, so is $X$, which is therefore $T_4$. On the other hand $A$ contains a copy of the Sorgenfrey line, whose square is not normal. Thus $X$ is not hereditarily normal. Finally note that $A$, and hence $X$, is first-countable, so both these spaces are have the point $G_\delta$ property.

Comment: @Alan My example is not in that book not its online variant [$\pi$-base](https://topology.jdabbs.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-use an example I used [recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4105695/4280) for another problem, use $X:=A \times A$ (in the product topology) where $A$ is Aleksandrov’s double arrow space (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_interval) e.g. or [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/double-arrow-space/)) which is compact, $T_5$, hereditarily Lindelöf, hereditarily separable but not metrisable and contains the [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) $\Bbb S$ as a subspace.

$X$ is compact Hausdorff, as the square of a compact Hausdorff space, so certainly $T_4$. It’s not $T_5$ because the subspace $\Bbb S \times \Bbb S$ is not normal.
$A$ is first countable and hence so is $X$, so all points are $G_\delta$ sets, but e.g. $\Delta = \{(x,x): x \in A\}$ is an example of a compact and closed subset that is *not* a $G_\delta$ set, e.g. So $A$ is an example of a $T_6$ space whose product is not $T_6$ as well.